# GitLab Runner not picking up jobs automatically after reboot

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

So our GitLab Runner was running fine for a few weeks now. I had to do some upgrades that required a reboot on the machine where it is installed.

After rebooting it no longer picks up jobs automatically. All my pipelines say they're stuck because there are no runners that could pick the jobs up.

I SSH'd into the machine and ran

```
sudo gitlab-runner run
```

and the jobs get picked up as I expect them to be. However when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it stops any picked up jobs and stops picking up any other jobs again. How do I fix this so that it's back to how it was before the reboot?

### Additional Info

When I ran

```
sudo gitlab-runner start
```

I got an error saying: `FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: "systemctl" failed: exit status 5, Failed to start gitlab-runner.service: Unit gitlab-runner.service not found.`

A similar error also popped up when I ran

```
sudo gitlab-runner restart
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So from the error message above it's saying the service isn't installed yet (not sure why). Running

```
gitlab-runner status
```

does say `gitlab-runner: Service is not installed.`

So I did

```
gitlab-runner install -u gitlab-runner
```

I'm not sure whether `gitlab-runner` is the default user that was used before this issue came up but I'll just use that here for now at least.

After installing the service I just issued

```
gitlab-runner start
```

And the jobs are getting picked up automatically again.

---

My only guess as to why this happened is because I ran `apt-get upgrade` which tried to upgrade all components with an update available which of course updated our version of GitLab Runner. Somehow that uninstalls the service? I'm not sure.

Comment: I've tried to install it and it gives me:
```
# gitlab-runner install -u gitlab-runner
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=170 revision=8925d9a0 version=14.1.0
FATAL: Failed to install gitlab-runner: Init already exists: /etc/init.d/gitlab-runner
```

Comment: @Rodolfo I'm not overly familiar with Linux so I'm just guessing here: perhaps gitlab-runner is already installed, just not running yet.. what does `gitlab-runner status` tell you? Maybe just do `gitlab-runner start` and see if that works for you.

Comment: I'm running it in a docker container, when I run `gitlab-runner status` it gives me `gitlab-runner: Service is not installed`

Comment: for more detail, you can check on the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html#using-binary-file