# How to connect gitlab with docker images from separate machine

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm running two machine with 2 local IP addresses

- machine1 with IP 10.2.3.105
- machine2 with IP 10.2.3.100
  In machine1, I install gitlab and gitlab-runner (local gitlab server)
  In machine2, I install docker and build my own image named ansible:2.9.27

I have run "gitlab-runner registry" on machine1 command to connect successfully to docker image on machine2 , but when I updated the ".gitlap-ci.yml", the job have this pending notify "This job is in pending state and is waiting to be picked by a runner".
Can someone please explain to me:

- Does it mean the registered docker image is on machine1 (gitlab server), and Do I need to install gitlap and docker in the same machine
- How can I connect to docker image with gitlab server in this situation. I've search many times on google but couldn't still find the resolution.

---

[image: This is the captured picture in my gitlab instance]

This is the captured picture in my gitlab instance

Comment: Since you registered your runner with your GitLab instance: Can you see the runner in your administrative interface under `Overview > Runners` and is it listed as `online`?

Comment: you mean in "Gitlab instance project --> Setting --> CICD --> Runners". If it's right, the runners is active.

Comment: There are multiple ways to configure a runner, but yes that way also works.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595158/gitlab-runner-not-picking-up-jobs-automatically-after-reboot) for additional guidance.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57005944/19238131) comment, you may also want to check if your `.gitlab-ci.yml` contains the appropriate tag selected for your runner.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I found the solution